# formData sends empty object to the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, axios, multipartform-data

I am working on a React app where I have to send files to the backend server using Axios. I have put an input element with its style as hidden and taken its value using userref hook. I store the values in a state variable. When I console this variable and `formData`, I can see the uploaded file in the console but when I send the request to the backend, it sends an empty array. I can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

My code is as follows:

```
const fileInputRef = useRef(null);
const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState([]);

const fileUpload = () => {
    fileInputRef.current.click();
};

const handleFileSelect = () => {
    const file = fileInputRef.current.files[0];
    setSelectedFiles([file]);
};
```

My API Request is given in the following function, which is triggered by a button:

```
const handleDocSubmission = () => {
    const file = selectedFiles[0];
    const formData = new FormData();
    if (file) {
        formData.append('document', file);
        console.log("Data", formData)
    }
    for (const [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(key, value);
    }
    try {
       axios.post("/upload/document", formData, {
          headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
        })
        alert("Your documents have been submitted!")
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    setSelectedFiles([])
}
```

Following are the JSX Componenets:

```
<input id="docUpload" type="file" ref={fileInputRef} onChange={handleFileSelect} style={{display: "none"}} />
<DocIcon sx={{fontSize: "72px", cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={fileUpload} />
<Button onClick={() => handleDocSubmission()} sx={{background:"#001d69", color: "#fff", margin: "10px 0"}}>
      Submit
</Button>
```

Comment: Can you please also add the backend handler code part?